# Where can I find the currently available Spinda form and when it changes in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Spinda has been around in Pokémon Go as a field research reward for [something over a year](https://pokemongohub.net/post/news/raikou-field-research-brings-spinda-shiny-snubbull-and-shiny-houndour/). Since then, Spinda forms [change at more or less fixed intervals](https://pokemongohub.net/post/news/october-suicune-field-research-guide-new-quests-shiny-krabby-new-spinda-form/) (typically monthly). Spinda remains only accessible by field research.

In my experience, the tasks giving Spinda have increased significantly in rarity since around March; I only found three in the past six months. I currently have one saved that I do not want to ‘waste’ on a Spinda form I already have (I know they are being rereleased as shinies but I consider the odds of encountering a shiny Spinda too low to ‘waste’ my Spinda catching chance on one).

Is there a place which lists the currently available Spinda form plus the time until/date when the next shuffle is expected? Bonus points for a site that includes a record of past available Spindas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various sites that will outline current tasks and what is available.  I personally use a combination of The Silph Road, and Leek Duck via Facebook.

The current Spinda, for November & December 2019, is #1.   Leek Duck normally includes the form number in their info graphics which are available on the site and Facebook.

[The Silph Road](https://thesilphroad.com/research-tasks)

[Leek Duck](https://leekduck.com/research/)

For info on previously released Spindas you can use this site:

[P337](https://p337.info/pokemongo/pages/spinda-release-dates/)

Currently released forms are:

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 4
5. 5
6. 6
7. 7
8. 8
9. 9